# C++ Program Not Outputting as expected (using .at, if/else, getline)

Tags: c++, if-statement, output, getline

For some reason my prototype program isn't outputting as expected.

My text file: (separated by tabs)

```
NameOne NameTwo NameThree   56789
```

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name1, name2, name3, name4, name5,fullName;
    ifstream inFile;
    string attendance;
    int index;

    inFile.open("test2.dat");
    getline(inFile, name1, '\t');
    getline(inFile, name2, '\t');
    getline(inFile, name3, '\t');
    if (name3.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    {
        attendance = name3;
        fullName = name1 + ' ' + name2;
    }
    else
    {
        getline(inFile, name4, '\t');
        if (name4.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        {
            attendance = name4;
            fullName = name1 + ' ' + name2 + ' ' + name3;
        }
        else
        {
            getline(inFile, name5, '\t');
            if (name5.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
            {
                attendance = name5;
                fullName = name1 + ' ' + name2 + ' ' + name3 + ' ' + name4;
            }
            else
            {
                fullName = name1 + ' ' + name2 + ' ' + name3 + ' ' + name4 + ' ' + name5;
                inFile >> attendance;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl << fullName << endl << attendance << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output :

```
NameOne NameTwo NameThree 
56789
```

Actual output:

```
NameOne NameTwo
NameThree
```

For some reason it's storing the string **NameThree** into attendance and outputting that.
I was expecting to store **NameFour** into attendance.

Comment: What do you expect `if (name3.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` to do ? Turn on compiler warnings and let the compiler point out the error of your ways.

Comment: What does `name3.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` suppose to mean?

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be downvoted, its OK in all respects

Comment: @barakmanos if the first character of the string is a number

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (name.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

To this:

```
if (isdigit(name.at(0)))
```

---

You have two different errors in your code:

1. The `if` statement is not properly structured (I'm surprised it even compiles)
2. In order to check if a character is the 0 digit, for example, you should compare it with `'0'` (not  `0`)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to turn on compiler warnings next time

Comment: @user3538295: *always* have compiler warnings enabled, and take notice of them, unless you enjoy guessing what the problems with your code might be.

Comment: _I'm surprised it even compiles_ - The result os this `name.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` is 9, because we have [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: @user2451677: It was more of a "manner of speaking", to emphasize that this is not an "ordinary coding habit". The fact that the language standard allows it, doesn't make it something that you'd want to put in your code (unless you're hoping to look at it again sometime in the future and ask yourself "what on earth did I have in mind here?").

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `if` statements:

```
if (isdigit(name.at(0)))
```

for the if statement as already stated in another answer.

Now for your stated questiom:

> "For some reason it's storing the string NameThree into attendance and outputting that. I was expecting to store NameFour into attendance."

This is because the expression in your first `if` passes.

```
name3.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

unfortunately evaluates to `true`.
The rest of your code (getting `name4` etc) is in the `else` block of that `if`.
Therefore, everything after the `if` is executed (and `attendance = name3;` is executed) and the rest of your code is not run until the end of the else block (and the following `cout`).

Remember, an `if` works like this:

```
if (expr)
{
   //run if expr == true
}
else
{
  //run if expr == false
}
```

and don't forget that `0` is `false`, and everything else is mapped to `true` when cast to `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering how

```
if (name4.at(0) == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

even compiles, it's because the C (and by extension C++) language defines `,` as a binary operator, like `/` or `->`. It has the lowest precedence, left-associativity, and its result is the value on the right-hand side. So the above expression is evaluated as:

```
(name4.at(0) == 0, 1) => 1
(1, 2) => 2
...
(8, 9) => 9
if(9) => true
```

(Adding to this, C++ even allows you to override `operator,`. It's strongly discouraged.)

Before you get too livid at this, bear in mind that this was how inline functions were implemented in the early, early days of C++, before there were native compilers and you used a tool called `cfront` to convert your C++ to C to then feed a C compiler. For example, if you wrote:

```
inline int List::read() const
{
    int x = *head++;
    if(head == end)
        head = begin;
    return x;
}
```

Then, when you actually called the function, `cfront` would insert something like

```
(__inl_x = *obj->head, ++obj->head, obj->head = (obj->head == obj->end? 
    obj->begin: obj->head), __inl_x)
```

into the calling expression. Note that the last thing in the `,`-separated list is the return value from the "inline" function. Needless to say, there were a lot of language constructs that weren't allowed in inline functions (much like there are many that aren't allowed in `constexpr` functions these days.)